# Get data from a site

Tags: .net, vb.net, import, split, vbcodeprovider

I want to get special data from a site but i don't know how.

I need a vb.net source code that help to get this data from web every 5 seconds and split them in a form.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Step 1: Be sure you have permission to scrape the site. Using someone's content without permission is illegal and hitting someone's website every 5 seconds can quickly get you IP-banned.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data on the webpage is compressed, so if you had been trying to get the data via `WebClient.DownloadString`, or `WebClient.DownloadData`, `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, then you would not get a readable string. The string might look like this

> ?y?] ?u??j?7?*s?H4??N???{?vS(????7?N?±A?O?f??E???-?O??q)?m,:K?:?{Ij.??J?Uem??-K?ni=KT???c?'?g??-??]??A???a?>???o*???????Ys??>??????5ga??Z[?v??s?F????i?eU?/?+,??!?f?9? t?2;bG???(??Y!??oX??Gm??W???????Z???8????=?y?WU??9??7;z?^??????T??Y?8]bih??|N?
>   ...

You can see that the encoding of the response is compressed with the following

```vb
client.ResponseHeaders(HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding)
' equals gzip
```

so doing simply

```vb
client.DownloadString(address)
```

will result in the compressed string. To account for compression, use `System.IO.GZipStream` to decompress.

This code is complete. All you do is make a new Form, add a new Label, and paste this

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly interval As Integer = 5000
    Private ReadOnly t As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf updateLabel, Nothing, -1, -1)
    Private ReadOnly address As String = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=35425587644337450&c=27+"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        t.Change(0, -1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub updateLabel(state As Object)
        Dim text As String
        Try
            text = getString(address)
            t.Change(interval, -1)
        Catch
            text = "error"
        End Try
        Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = text)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function getString(address As String) As String
        Dim text As String
        Using client As New Net.WebClient()
            Using stream = client.OpenRead(address)
                If client.ResponseHeaders(Net.HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding) = "gzip" Then
                    Using responseStream = New IO.Compression.GZipStream(stream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                        Using reader = New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                            text = reader.ReadToEnd()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Else
                    Using reader = New IO.StreamReader(stream)
                        text = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    End Using
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
        Return text
    End Function

End Class
```

The code above allows either compressed or non-compressed responses. If you know it's always compressed, you can just use this

```vb
Private Shared Function getString(address As String) As String
    Dim text As String
    Using client As New Net.WebClient()
        Using stream = client.OpenRead(address)
            Using responseStream = New IO.Compression.GZipStream(stream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                Using reader = New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                    text = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return text
End Function
```

You should now be getting a readable string

> 12:29:37,A ,5254,5218,5203,5223,5277,5190,1727,16938744,88393224291,1,20191125,122937;98/9/4 14:31:01,F,308477.15,2703.04 0.88%,11256322598042802,2998595530,15357456521865,388202,F,986363991,12363278355103,190712,F,606761,179231120000,6176,;4@63890@5230@5254@100000@2,4@120000@5228@5255@6500@1,2@40000@5222@5259@221500@6,;65589,406538,760335;10352685,6586059,0,14312016,2626728,573,19,0,456,12;;;0;